# TeeChart How to force a Mark to behave the same as a Pointer?

Tags: delphi, teechart, delphi-10.1-berlin

Delphi 10.1, Windows 10 Pro x64, TeeChart pro 2017.20.
For LineSeries chart with alot of points (1471 points), I would like to show a selective one Mark, defined in code.
I can see the Mark only if I zoom the window enough.
There are situations, with some partial zoom, the Mark is shown and hiden while dragging (PAN) the chart with right mouse (see pictures).
[Visible Mark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7TNR.png)
[Un visible mark, same resolution as previous, just moved (PAN)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDxmM.png)

On the other hand, a pointer is behave exactly as I want. I can always see it on ant zoom.
Here is a short code with Marks and Pointers for demonstration:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Series: tLineSeries;
  i: integer;
begin
  // Chart settings
  Chart1.Align  := alClient;
  Chart1.View3D := false;

  // LineSeries definition
  Series:=Chart1.AddSeries(TLineSeries.Create(Self)) as tLineSeries;
  Series.FillSampleValues(1471);

  // Marks
  Series.Marks.Visible := true; // Global flag
  //Series.Marks.AutoPosition := false;
  //Series.Marks.Automatic.Move:= false;
  for i := 0 to Series.Count-1 do
    Series.Marks[i].Visible := false;
  Series.Marks[506].Visible := true;

  // Pointers
  Series.Pointer.Visible := true;  // Global flag
  for i := 0 to Series.Count-1 do
    Series.Pointer[i].Visible := false;
  Series.Pointer[506].Visible := true;
end;
```

How to force a Mark to behave the same as a Pointer?

Comment: Cannot reproduce with v2016.17.160129. I mean, marks with the above code in this version disappear when the pointer gets out of the view.

Comment: Thanks Victoria, was it with Delphi? If yes, which version? I think 2016.17 is not for 10.1

Comment: Yes, it's from Tokyo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TeeChart calculates the minimum "Draw Every" step, when there are more marks to
display than available pixels. This optimization interferes with your setup.
Try setting this to skip this optimization:

```
Series.CalcVisiblePoints:=False;
```

Comment: Thanks Yeray, That's it. It is probably a new feature, since Victoria reported there was no issu on v2016.17.

Comment: The `CalcVisiblePoints` was present from much earlier, but it was used to control this "Draw Every" optimization since it was introduced, in v2016.19